# Django- Cleaning data for a many-to-many field within ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building an API that will require the cleaning of input data into a modelform m2m field before creating the model instance.

The data will come in as a string of names, I will need to clean the data and add link the m2m relationship manually.

What is the proper way to link these relationships within the manytomany field during the clean Def. Do I simply append each into the field itself?

Below is my working "clean" def:

```
def clean_sourcingbroker(self):
        broker = self.cleaned_data['broker']
        cleanlist = []
        names = []
        for name in broker.replace(', ', ',').split(' '): 
            name = name.split(',')
            last_name = name[0]
            first_name = name[1]
            names.append((last_name, first_name))
        for name in names:
            brokerobj = Broker.objects.get(lastname=name[0], firstname=name[1])
            cleanlist.append(brokerobj)
        return cleanlist
```

Comment: If you're building an API you should really look into django-rest-framework rather than using forms.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the comment- so far I've used djangorest for getting specific data- what is the proper terminology of creating a model instance through DjangoRest? Is it possible to clean the data like i am doing above before creating the instance?

Comment: [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# If you want to change the value of a field, then you can use

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    validatedData = (super(SerializerClass, self).to_internal_value(data))
    broker = validatedData["broker"]
    cleanlist = []
    names = []
    for name in broker.replace(', ', ',').split(' '):
        name = name.split(',')
        last_name = name[0]
        first_name = name[1]
        names.append((last_name, first_name))
    for name in names:
        brokerobj = Broker.objects.get(lastname=name[0], firstname=name[1])
        cleanlist.append(brokerobj)

    validatedData["broker"] = cleanlist
    return validatedData


# If you want to validate the field, then you can use

def validate(self, data):
    if len(data['broker']) == 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("validation error for broker field")
    return data
```